# Get current milliAmps of battery

Tags: android

How to get current battery capacity in mA of android device.

I have tried this code, but it gives me value total battery capacity:

```
public void getBatteryCapacity() {
     Object mPowerProfile_ = null;
     final String POWER_PROFILE_CLASS = "com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile";
    try {
        mPowerProfile_ = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
            .getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        double batteryCapacity = (Double) Class
            .forName(POWER_PROFILE_CLASS)
            .getMethod("getAveragePower", java.lang.String.class)
            .invoke(mPowerProfile_, "battery.capacity");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, batteryCapacity + " mah",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
```

Comment: that's not possible. `PowerProfile` gives you what each component uses when active. It contains only static information from an XML file that defines how the device behave.

Comment: You re right, thank you.
Do you know other way to get battery current capacity in mA

Comment: you can register to the battery intents to receive updates : https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html